# Opening a PHP file with a URL without file extension from Java Servlet

Tags: java, php, servlets

My problem seems a little bit weird but I'm unable to find a solution.
I have a Java servlet that has to connect via POST to a PHP file with a URL without extension.

Here is a part of the code in the Java servlet:

```
/**
 * The POST client (for authentication and data retrieval)
 * @param entity
 * @return Server Response
 */
private Response postRequest(Representation entity) {

    Request r = new Request();
    r.setResourceRef("http://xxx.ac.at/privis/chameleoninterface");
    r.setMethod(Method.POST);
    r.setEntity(entity); 
    Response response = new Client(Protocol.HTTP).handle(r);
    System.out.println("\nServer Response: " + response.getStatus() + "\n");
    return response;            
}
```

Behind the URL

> http://xxx.ac.at/privis/chameleoninterface

It should connect with the PHP-file chameleoninterface.php and it should in turn open.
**IMPORTANT: I'm not allowed to add .php at the end of the URL.**
The code is working without any problems due to previous checks with the file extension at the end.

Is there any other possibility of solving this problem?

Thanks,
Arci

Comment: Please add some information about what web server you are using if you would like a more detailed response.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

1. You can use [url rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/) to map `/privis/chameleoninterface` to `/privis/chameleoninterface.php`
2. You can put `index.php` file that has all the code from `chameleoninterface.php` in a directory named `chameleoninterface` [this is the simplest way to do it]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll try the url rewrite!I already tried your 2nd advice, but this didn't work.

Comment: The problem is, I'm not allowed to do one of those two ways.
If I use #1 I would modify the servlet
If I use #2 it won't be possible to call 3 different files (depending on the request from the browser to the servlet) in the chameleoninterface folder

I have to solve the problem in another way... :(